# Angucomplete: console log input value

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to console log the angucomplete input value.

If I write "w," it should console log "W".

If I add the letter "o" it will new console log "Wo".

Usually I console the ng-model, but here I can't.

```
 <angucomplete-alt id="ex1"
                                          placeholder="Customer Name"
                                          pause="100"
                                          selected-object="selected"
                                          local-data="tickets"
                                          search-fields="title"
                                          title-field="title"
                                          minlength="0"
                                          ng-click="search()"
                                          input-class="form-control"
                                          style="margin-top: 15px">
                        </angucomplete-alt>
```

I need to send that value to SQL, for search
with ng-model is easy, im just sending ng-model.

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt/issues/481 this will help you i guess

Comment: THANKS :), helped me